# Flask command running in an environment and not running in another

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a flask app that are running in a local machine when runing `flask run` but it's not running in an AWS EC2.

- Both environment have Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.
- Both are running in virtualenvs created in the same way and path (only user's folder is different).
- Both have the same Flask version.
- Both have `python-dotenv` and `.flaskenv` file and are set to
  development and debug.
- Both have the same project folder (same git repo) and I `flask run`
  in the same folder for both.
- I defined the PORT in `.flaskenv` and I can see that the PORT defined
  in there is where flask is running in both.

When I try to get the same URL, in EC2 I got an error: `NoAppException: Could not import "app.initialize"`

Running in local machine:

```
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.initialize:web_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5324/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 179-083-368
```

Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 09:10:13] "GET /api/directors/me/info HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Running un EC2:

```
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.initialize:web_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5324/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 104-758-876
```

Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2019 12:05:42] "GET /api/directors/me/info HTTP/1.0" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 325, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 313, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 302, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 371, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
    'Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name)
NoAppException: Could not import "app.initialize".
```

For this app, I have a custom flask command and when I try to call this command for both environment, on the local machine works fine, but in EC2 I got a `No such command` error.

I really tried everything I found in SO about checking if things are getting imported right, packages versions and etc. In EC2, when I `ipython`, I can `import app.initialize` and I can even import models and use my app code to run things, including the command function.

Finally, if I run this app using Gunicorn in EC2, its works fine, but sometime I need to run with flask for debug (its a sandbox environment) and I need to run custom commands too.

Any idea what may be wrong in EC2?

Ty All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the path to `app` to the ec2's python path. If you're in the directory of the project, run `export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH"`.

Basically if your project looks something like this in the file system:

```
/home
  /myuser
    /myproject
      /app
        __init__.py
        somemodule.py
```

Then you want to have `/home/myuser/myproject` present in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

You'll want to automate this since that environment variable will only be present in the shell you ran the command in. To do that you these are some potential options:

- There may be a way for you to configure environment variables via the AWS UI (not sure).
- You can create or use an image that already has `PYTHONPATH` set up and make sure you put your project in the path.
- You can add the export command to `~/.profile` if you are running a shell as the same user that will be running the application, or `/etc/profile` if you just want to add the path to the application for all users. Then reboot the server.

But before worrying about that, to test that the solution is correct follow these steps:

1. SSH into the ec2 instance
2. Start a python shell with `python`
3. Run this statement (it should fail due to an import error): `import app.initialize`
4. Exit the shell with exit() or ctrl-d
5. Export the path to `app`
6. Repeat steps 2-3, except this time they should succeed

Comment: `import app.initialize` works in `python` and in `ipython` if I run it from the project folder, where the app folder is. And that is what causing more trouble, because I always thought the current folder will always been add to the PYTHONPATH by default in linux because this test worked. Don't know why the import worked in python without the folder set in PYTHONPATH, but `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/my-user/project-folder & flask run` worked. Thank you Sam, I will set this var in my environment.